# Adding close button next to an image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this code:

```html
<style type="text/css"> 
.containerdiv { position:relative;width:100%;display:inline-block;} 
.image1 { position: absolute; top: 20px; left: 10px; }

</style>

<div class="containerdiv">

<image src="https://media.gettyimages.com/photos/perfect-wood-planks-background-picture-id523584249?b=1&amp;k=6&amp;m=523584249&amp;s=612x612&amp;w=0&amp;h=LJ8b5cbwCLJU7iZAPSbm5skekvf_Vy7RZbgACH6Ze8g=" style="border:none;position:absolute;width:612px;height:612px;"></iframe>

<img class="image1" border="0" src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-_RSqh-pRVbE/VYkvXSK0f3I/AAAAAAAAAIQ/efZ1rnXb-_g/s320/manchester-united-fc.png" alt="" width="350px" height="318px">


</div>
```

I'd like to add simple close button 'x' next to the soccer club image (in the top right corner after the image) so when I click on that close button then the soccer club image should dissapear and will hide.Thank you

Comment: and the question is ? any particular issue ? why the JAVA flag ?

Comment: Well what have you tried so far?

Comment: You have a misplaced iframe tag in place of an ending image tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After what happened yesterday, I feel compelled to help out a United fan...
https://jsfiddle.net/q724sb3o/10/

I changed a couple of your elements to give them ID instead of class, and added a simple button to make the image disappear (the button also disappears).

HTML

```
<div class="containerdiv">

<image src="https://media.gettyimages.com/photos/perfect-wood-planks-background-picture-id523584249?b=1&amp;k=6&amp;m=523584249&amp;s=612x612&amp;w=0&amp;h=LJ8b5cbwCLJU7iZAPSbm5skekvf_Vy7RZbgACH6Ze8g=" style="border:none;position:absolute;width:612px;height:612px;" />

<img id="image1" border="0" src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-_RSqh-pRVbE/VYkvXSK0f3I/AAAAAAAAAIQ/efZ1rnXb-_g/s320/manchester-united-fc.png" alt="" width="350px" height="318px" />
<span id="close" onClick="hideImg()">X</span>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.containerdiv { position:relative;width:100%;display:inline-block;} 
#image1 { position: absolute; top: 20px; left: 10px; }
#close {position:absolute; top: 0px; left: 350px; font-size: 32px; cursor: pointer }
```

JS

```
function hideImg() {
  document.getElementById("image1").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("close").style.display = "none";
}
```